# Is this PayPal e-mail a scam?

Tags: email, spam, scam, paypal

I just received this e-mail (where the blacked out parts are my e-mail address):

[image: Screenshot of PayPal email.]

To me it looks like a scam for the following reasons:

- First of all, I do not have a Paypal account.
- It is written in english, which is not my native language.
- It asks me to click a link, to insert right away my credentials and to change them right after.

Now I am trying to understand what is going on. I just checked my bank account and no unauthorized transaction has been done. I have not clicked that link yet of course, but should I get worried or just mark it off as a scam?

Comment: I would reach out directly to PayPal for support: https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/How-do-I-report-potential-fraud-to-PayPal-FAQ2422

Comment: @Eric G Thank you for the link, but to reach out to PayPal trought the website I need to be logged in and I do not have an account. I will call PayPal support ASAP.

Comment: Since you don't have an account with them, that's 100% assurance that you're looking at a forgery.  And since English isn't your native tongue you probably don't recognize the poor grammar, which is another strong indicator that it's a forgery.  It's probably mostly a waste of your time contacting PayPal; I'd just discard it and move on.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ... or just mark it off as a scam?

I would recommend this option, i.e. simply ignore this mail. There is a lot of Paypal phishing mails out there because Paypal accounts are a lucrative target. But given that you don't have a Paypal account in the first place this mail is obviously a scam.

You still should learn from this mail that such mails can happen with sites and services where you have real accounts too. Similar phishing mails are sent also for example to get access to Apple, Netflix, Amazon and various bank  and mail accounts.

Answer (score 1):

**There's only one rule here: do not click on any link ever !**

If you want to check your account, just log in to it separately.

Clicking a link may be dangerous or not and many times it does take some deeper digging to see what's actually behind it.

Comment: This. Actually, some German banks have actually taken this to heart: In reminder emails they send, they deliberately do not include a link, but just tell you to "please log in to your account to view this information".

Comment: @sleske same in the UK

Answer (score 0):

Look at [PayPals help page](https://www.paypal.com/us/selfhelp/article/How-to-spot-fake-emails-FAQ2340). It says they never say "Dear [your email address]", which is what it is saying in your image. So in conclusion it is a scam!